# Can I use Attiny insted of Arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, atmel, attiny, attiny85

can anyone suggest me that, can i use a Attiny85 instead of Arduino uno board? and how it can be posible?

Comment: Too many details in above question.

Comment: AL BUNDY, Sir I didnt get you, that what you said!!

Comment: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arjun/programming-attiny85-with-arduino-uno-afb829 your question is unclear. but, i hope you are clear with your question.

Comment: @Umar, yes sir, I am clear with my question, I want to develop a project which uses less space, that's why I am asking , can I use two Attiny85 as an alternative to Arduino UNO board?

Comment: @GauravKesharwani Well I don't see what's stopping you.

Comment: @Bradman175 Sir, I am not getting idea to to implement it!

Comment: https://divnoblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/12/ this is my project using ATmega328 (same as Arduino Uno without the fancy board - could be as well done with Attiny85 (with slighly different schema) - just timer with simple inputs/outputs, but usefull for making PCBs . On the other hand my current project (mobile robot) now contains 3 Arduino MiniPro (same power, other factor than Uno) and it is still now enought - for 3 Attiny85 it would be impossible to do, even for 5. maybe 15-20.  So it depends on what your project exactly is.

Comment: Maybe the first thing you could do is put some effort (punctuation and grammar) into your question, and read the guidelines of the site.

Comment: @laptop2d ok sir!

Comment: Your question says 1 x tiny. Your comment says two. That'snot clear. | List the resources on each susyem (digital IUO, analog IO, UART, USB, ...) List what your project needs. Decide if tiny meets need. If not decide how requirement can be adapted

Comment: @GauravKesharwani Google is your friend. There is a way to program normal Arduino code through an Arduino uno into the attiny just search it up.

Answer (score 3):

> **Can I use Attiny insted of Arduino uno?**

Yes.

If you are only using a few IO pins and have no special requirements for speed or other facilities found in the ATMega328 and not in, for example, an ATtiny85.

Web search for "Shrinkify Arduino"

> The ATtiny45 or 85 is a great option for running simple Arduino programs: it’s small, cheap and relatively easy to use. It does, however, have some limitations relative to the ATmega328P on an Arduino Uno. There are fewer pins, meaning you can’t connect as many components. There’s less flash memory (4KB or 8KB instead of 32KB), meaning your programs can’t be as big. There’s less RAM (256 or 512 bytes instead of 2KB), meaning you can’t store as much data. And there’s no hardware serial port or I2C port (Wire library), making communication trickier. (There are workarounds, like the SoftwareSerial library or the TinyWire library, but they’re not as robust and flexible.)
>
> In short, then, if your project requires only a few simple inputs and/or outputs, you’re probably fine using an ATtiny. If you’re trying to hook up more components or do more complex communication or data processing, though, you’re probably better off with something like the ATmega328P on an Arduino Uno. If you want something smaller and cheaper than a full Arduino board, you might try using an ATmega328P on a breadboard instead.

- [MIT high-low tech](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695)

---

[image]

"Blink" sketch running on an ATtiny85.

---

[image]

An ATtiny85 based Arduino-like development board.

[image]

Another.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but depends on what you need. Bot are microprocessors, if you need to light LED on some simple sensor/button, then it should not be problem. But Arduino Uno have standardised headers ont he board and more pins/functions and more power/ram/etc. So it can do more complicated things.

You can play cards on smartphone, laptop, PC or gaming PC as well. You cannot play new AAA+++ game on smartphone and on laptop you get max really low details and laggy output. How it is possible? (That is the same kind of question)

---

UNO is basically power stabiliser + USB/serial converter + atmega328 with oscilator + fancy headers in somehow standardized pattern, so shields fit. Cannot just change the schema and put Attiny85 there, as there is not enought pins for all connector. Can make PCB with some restricted functionality (less IO) with Attin85 and use it for simpler experiments. Many experiments with UNO use just 2-4 pins, so the UNO is overkill. Many use much more so the Attiny would not suffice.

Sometimes is better to make your own PCB with either atmega328 ot Attin85, or more, maybe even in combination. All depends on what experiment you want to make

Comment: Sir i will put headers and oscillator circuit, i measure space for it , even I am developing my own development board it will use less space than Arduino UNO, but actual thing is I am not getting Idea to replace Arduino by Attiny

Comment: UNO is basically power stabiliser + USB/serial converter + atmega328 + fancy headers in somehow standardized pattern, so shileds fit. Cannot just change the schema and put Attiny85 there, as there is not enought pins for all connector. Can make PCB with some restricted functionality (less IO) with Attin85 and use it for simpler experiments. Many experiments witn UNO use just 2-4 pins, so the UNO is overkill. Many use much more so the Attiny would not suffice.

Comment: @gilhad, please add that comment to your answer instead of the last paragraph.

Comment: I see an awful lot of Uno projects that can be done on an ATtiny13 (like 3 wires people, really), it boils down to resources.  If size is an issue, might I suggest the Adafruit Mini Metro, just have a look. For a modest project, the ATTiny85 is ideal, but you really only have 5 IO pins easily and you lose 2 of them for external clock. The libraries are not as extensive either.

Comment: "If you have only hammer, everithing looks like a nail" - lot of people got Arduino kit, did some demo with it and then got IDEA - something like if I can blink LED, rotare powerful motor and read thermo, I coud as well blink heat lamp for my turtles when it is too cold but turn it off, when it is warm. Look what I have here - Arduino UNO, thermo, transistor, I just buy heat lamp, bang it together and my turtles would be happy. And so they do. Even it there are more appropriate tools (which needs more knowledge to use), like PIC10F ( see http://www.fucik.name/masinky/mini_light/ )